# Angular Lazy loading: loadChildren different behaviours

Tags: angular, lazy-loading, angular-routing, angular-lazyloading

Guys i have an angular application with lazy loading enabled and below modules.

CoreModule, (import in app module)
SharedModule, (imported in each module)
ProjectsModule,
AuthModule

And this is my app routing module:

```
    { path: "",             redirectTo: "auth/sign-in", pathMatch: "full" },
// { path: "auth",      loadChildren: () => AuthModule }, // Bundled in main js file
{ path: "auth",         loadChildren: () => import("@core/auth/auth.module").then(p => p.AuthModule) },
{ path: "projects",     loadChildren: () => import("@projects/projects.module").then(p => p.ProjectsModule) }
```

when using **dynamic import** syntax in root app routing module the javascript bundles fetched in browser are below ones: (refreshing /auth/sign-in)

- core-auth-auth-module.js
- default~core-auth-auth-module~projects-projects-module.js
- projects-projects-module.js (Preloading)

1- So what exactly are modules 1 and 2?

Then when i'm using function syntax on loadchildren first 2 modules don't get load in browser.

2- What's the difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is that in case of using `import` keyword your modules are loaded lazily while `loadChildren: () => AuthModule` syntax will bundle AuthModule in main js file.

*- So what exactly are modules 1 and 2?*

You told Angular(webpack) to lazy load AuthModule  by using `import` keyword. Webpack noticed this instruction and created dedicated lazy chunk with a name based on module path:

```
import("@core/auth/auth.module")
               ||
               \/
      core-auth-auth-module.js chunk
```

So, the first chunk is where your `AuthModule` resides.

But Angular CLI uses webpack under the hood and it does some magic behind the scene with the help of SplitChunksPlugin[<sup>ref</sup>](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/split-chunks-plugin/).

This webpack plugin tries to minimize duplication in your code and extract additional bundles from lazy modules.

```
default~core-auth-auth-module~projects-projects-module.js
                ||                        ||
                \/                        \/
            AuthModule                   ProjectsModule
```

This chunk contains common code shared between `AuthModule` and `ProjectsModule`.

You can also dig deeper for details in my article:

- [Code-splitting in Angular or how to share components between lazy modules](https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/angular-code-splitting-or-how-to-share-components-between-lazy-modules-432c755e389c)